# Width change of one row moves the whole div up

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create an overlay for the website, it should have the form of three boxes stacked on top of each other. Currently, they are situated so that the first two are on the first row, and the third one is on the bottom. To make them all be on a separate row, I am trying to add single parameter to css: `width: 100%`, which worked for the third row, but ruins everything if I do it to either of the ones left.

Here is the code snippet, It will work on its own:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#box {
  width: 70vw;
  height: 80vh;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.column4 {
  height: 39vh;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  padding: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1.3;
  /*width: 100%;*/ /* here is the culprit*/
}

.column5 {
  height: 39vh;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1.3;
}

#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#boxt3 {
  font-size: 25px;
}

#boxt1 {
  font-size: 20px;
}

#boxt2 {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay" style="z-index: 100; display: block;" onclick="off()">
  <div id="text">
    <div id="box" style="background:#fff">
      <div class="row">
        <div id="boxt1" class="column4" style="padding-top: 0; overflow: auto">Facebook, Inc.<br>NASDAQ<br>US<br>Internet Content &amp; Information<br>Communication Services<br>some nice info</div>
        <div id="boxt2" class="column4" style="padding-top: 0; overflow: auto">Price: 341.00 <br>mCap: 965.39B<br>Beta: 1.295305<br>volAvg: 14142012<br>P/E: NA</div>
        <div class="column5" style="padding-top: 5; overflow: auto">
          <h2 id="boxt3" stle="">Key features:<br> Net income: 6969% year-to-year<br> Undervalued on Very% by P/S<br>We love your data -Mark<br><br> Estimated probability of success: 0<br></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I understand that there is probably some dumb mistake, but I can't find it at all (I have just started learning :) ). What is the issue here?

Comment: May I ask why are you using height for the parent container ?

Comment: @Viira This was not a very clear question, however, this gave an idea of how to solve this, the issue was that the height for columns that I have set was just too large for three rows, which makes html freak out. You can post it as the answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Great I'll make it as an answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue occurs because you have set the height for the child element which is too high `(39vh + 39vh + 39vh)` for the parent element `(80vh)` . Try fitting the height of the child elements into parent's height. It will fix your problem.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#box {
  width: 70vw;
  height: 80vh;
  /*margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;*/
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.column4 {
  height: 20vh;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  padding: 50px 50px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1.3;
  width: 100%;
}
*{box-sizing:border-box;}
.column5 {
  height: 40vh;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1.3;
}

#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#boxt3 {
  font-size: 25px;
}

#boxt1 {
  font-size: 20px;
}

#boxt2 {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay" style="z-index: 100; display: block;" onclick="off()">
  <div id="text">
    <div id="box" style="background:#fff">
      <div class="row">
        <div id="boxt1" class="column4" style="padding-top: 0; overflow: auto">Facebook, Inc.<br>NASDAQ<br>US<br>Internet Content &amp; Information<br>Communication Services<br>some nice info</div>
        <div id="boxt2" class="column4" style="padding-top: 0; overflow: auto">Price: 341.00 <br>mCap: 965.39B<br>Beta: 1.295305<br>volAvg: 14142012<br>P/E: NA</div>
        <div class="column5" style="padding-top: 5; overflow: auto">
          <h2 id="boxt3" stle="">Key features:<br> Net income: 6969% year-to-year<br> Undervalued on Very% by P/S<br>We love your data -Mark<br><br> Estimated probability of success: 0<br></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I have set the child element's height to `20vh + 20vh + 40vh` sums up to the height of the parent's height `80vh`

Answer (score 0):

*You must remove width: 100% from column5 class*

Answer (score 0):

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#box {
  width: 70vw;
  height: 80vh;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.column4 {
  height: 39vh;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  padding: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1.3;
  /*width: 100%;*/ /* here is the culprit*/
}

.column5 {
  height: 39vh;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1.3;
}

#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#boxt3 {
  width : 50px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

#boxt1 {
    width : 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#boxt2 {
    width : 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: This just makes it into three columns, not rows, and they are really small, If I try to make them larger, the same issue occurs. See the image: https://imgur.com/a/vemdpJ2

Comment: Extend items in pixels /// ===> .column5 {
  width : 200px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

#boxt1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  width : 200px;
}

#boxt2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  width : 200px;
}

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="overlay" style="z-index: 100; display: block;" onclick="off()">
  <div id="text">
    <div id="box" style="background:#fff">
      <div class="row">
        <div id="boxt1" class="column4" style="padding-top: 0; overflow: auto">Facebook, Inc.<br>NASDAQ<br>US<br>Internet Content &amp; Information<br>Communication Services<br>some nice info</div>
        <div id="boxt2" class="column4" style="padding-top: 0; overflow: auto">Price: 341.00 <br>mCap: 965.39B<br>Beta: 1.295305<br>volAvg: 14142012<br>P/E: NA</div>
        <div class="column5" style="padding-top: 5; overflow: auto">
          <h2 id="boxt3" stle="">Key features:<br> Net income: 6969% year-to-year<br> Undervalued on Very% by P/S<br>We love your data -Mark<br><br> Estimated probability of success: 0<br></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```